# J2EE performance degradation - application running on windows with tomcat

Tags: java, windows, performance, sockets, tomcat

I have a j2ee application running on windows, the application is running fantastic for first 5 min, then after 5 min I see a severe performance degradation.

On the java flight controller I see some time spent on WAIT and Socket Read
But I am not sure how to analyze this further,
This is just a guess but Is there any limitation on windows on sockets/connections like on linux?
in linux max number of sockets/ files is configured in /etc/security/limits.conf

[image: flight controller]

Comment: There is an open file handle limitations in Windows as well, but it's not clear how those events could fit the one minute interval on that screenshot to make any conclusion. Judging by numbers your app spent more time in lock contention then waiting for network. You would get an error TooManyOpenFiles if that's the numbers of sockets stalling your app. If that's not the case - you would need to gather a thread dump and find out what your threads are waiting for.

Comment: your app spent more time in lock contention -> how to dig more into that?

Comment: First of all you need describe what sort of performance degradaton do you see. If this thing is an indicator of 'bad' lock contention - you could spot it by getting a Java thread dumps (several times with a minimal interval), or you could attach a profiler (VisualVM, YourKit whatever) they show amount of running/blocked threads.